# If $f$ continuous at $[0,1]$ and $f(x) >0$ for all rational $x$, prove that $f(x) >0$ may be not true for irrational $x$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to use ε to prove this. If I put ε the minimum  irrational number near 0 then f(x0) must be <= minimum rational number near 0,so that lim f(x) x_>x0 should be 0.I don't know if this is a right approach or there is a more efficient way to prove this.  Thanks

Comment: To settle the point, all you need is a single example...no general proof is called for.

Comment: also, what is the "minimum irrational number near $0$"?

Comment: Despite of the two upvotes, I delete my (wrong) answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try a function like $$f(x)=| x-\alpha|$$ where $\alpha$ is your favorite irrational in the given range.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$
f(x) = | x - 1/\pi| .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Example where $f(x)>0$ for all rationals as well as for all irrationals:
$$ f(x)=1.$$

Example where $f(x)>0$ for all rationals but not for all irrationals in $[0,1]$:
$$ f(x)=(2x^2-1)^2.$$

Comment: OK, thanks you.